# UNION ALL query: "Too Many Fields Defined"

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to get a UNION of 3 tables, each of which have 97 fields.  I've tried the following:

```
select * from table1
union all
select * from table2
union all
select * from table3
```

This gives me an error message:

```
Too many fields defined.
```

I also tried explicitly selecting all the field names from the first table (ellipses added for brevity):

```
select [field1],[field2]...[field97] from table1
union all
select * from table2
union all
select * from table3
```

It works fine when I only UNION two tables like this:

```
select * from table1
union all
select * from table2
```

I shouldn't end up with more than 97 fields as a result of this query; the two-table UNION only has 97.  So why am I getting `Too many fields` with 3 tables?

EDIT: As RichardTheKiwi notes below, Access is summing up the field count of each SELECT query in the UNION chain, which means that my 3 tables exceed the 255 field maximum.  So instead, I need to write the query like this:

```
select * from table1
union all
select * from
(select * from table2
union all
select * from table3)
```

which works fine.

Comment: the tables that are `UNION`ed need to have the same number of fields, and they should be in the same order and of the same type..

Comment: @sigil If you share schema of your 3 tables that will be very helpful to solve your issue. Anyhow Whatever Gaby aka suggested thats really important for union

Comment: @Gabyakagpetrioli They do have the same number of fields, in the same order, and the same type.  And the `UNION` works fine when I pair any two tables.  It's just when I do 3 tables that it fails.

Comment: Why does this have 97 columns, your database sounds horrific.  Also, here is a fiddle that works with 3 tables using only * selects:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c8d0/2

Comment: @sigil commenting on your edit: If the first two tables(which is table1 and table2) has more than 255 fields it will give the same error. So you need to have less than 128 fields in your union all

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appears that the number of fields being tracked (limit 255) is counted against ALL parts of the UNION ALL. So 3 x 97 = 291, which is in excess.  You could probably create a query as a UNION all of 2 parts, then another query with that and the 3rd part.

Comment: good to know about access.  Still concerning that it is 97 columns.

Answer (score 1):

I had two tables with 173 fields each (2 x 173 > 255!). So I had to resort to splitting the tables in half (keeping the primary key in both), before using the UNION statement and reassembling the resulting output tables using a JOIN.

```
    select u1.*, u2.* 
    from (
      select [field1_PKID],[field2],...,[field110] 
      from table1

      union all

      select [field1_PKID],[field2],...,[field110] 
      from table2
      ) as u1
    inner join (
      select [field1_PKID],[field111],...,[field173] 
      from table1

      union all 

      select [field1_PKID],[field111],...,[field173] 
      from table2
      ) as u2
    on [u1].[field1_PKID] = [u2].[field2_PKID]
```

Comment: What an ingenious workaround! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if your 3 tables have duplicate records you can go with UNION instead of UNION ALL which may reduce the number of fields to be tracked. Because UNION will always serve the business purpose which removes duplicates. In that case your query will be like following,

```
select * from table1
union
select * from table2
union
select * from table3;
```