# SQL Statement with Classic ASP

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I have a form with a select drop-down which is populated from a database, when the form is submitted I get the results from the selection

```
  SQL_query = "SELECT * from Flytasks where waabase like '"+waabase+"'"
```

I would like to have the option to select the word "ALL" from the drop-down and need a single select statement that when ALL is selected it returns all the records, the word ALL is not in the database.

Is this possible ?

Many thanks in advance

Rob

Comment: This code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: Its just a simple example so I can try and get a answer to my question

Comment: Don't spread vulnerable code where someone who doesn't know better could see and emulate it, even with simple examples.

Comment: How is someone meant to explain something without examples ?

Comment: Use an example that isn't vulnerable to the biggest hack on the web.

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with it >

Comment: Think about what happens if this (or something similarly evil) ends up in the waabase variable: `';DROP Table Flybase;--` I could send a malicious http request to your site with _anything_ as the value for that input field, even in drop down lists.

Comment: I wouldn't bother @JoelCoehoorn it falls on deaf ears anyway. There are too many questions that ask using poor SQL and too many answers given with poor SQL that are accepted or even voted up.

Comment: The % sign can be used for wildcard searches in SQL, so `<option value="%">ALL</option>` would give `waabase` a value of `%` and return all the records in the table.  I'm not going to post this as an answer - use at your own risk and take the warnings about SQL injection attacks seriously - especially if it is a public facing website

Comment: I am new to all this but just can't see how anyone can inject anything into the sql statment above unless you hack the actual pages. If the values where sent though the address bar using GET then I can see how this could be achived. I am using POST method how can anyone submit a value to waabase. If I am wrong then please say. The last site I wrote from sratch was a shopping cart and thats checked once a month for PCI compliance via Barclays severs and one of the checks is for SQL injection attacks and its passed every time, surly what I am doing can't be that wrong ?

Comment: Hackers don't need to edit your pages, they can create their own  `<form metnod="Post" action="http://your.external.url">`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, explain to me how this is vulnerable to SQL injection, given that you know ABSOLUTELY NOTHING about what the `waabase` variable contains. (You *assume* you know, but you can't *actually* know, because that's not part of the example.) For example, what if the first thing I did was `waabase = Replace(Request.Form("waabase"),"'","''")`? This knee-jerk "OMG SQL INJECTION!!!!1" stuff gets old really really fast.

Comment: @Martha First of all, `Replace("string", "'", "''")` is _not_ an okay way to protect against injection attacks (better than nothing, but still not correct). Second, I do know that waabase is provided from an html select input, which means I can very probably craft an http request to put anything I want in there. It's important to promote correct practices.

Comment: It surprises me how people still believe `Replace()` is adequate to sanitise form variables. SQL Injection should not be taken so lightly. I tell you what I find old @Martha, attitudes that play down the need to protect against SQL Injection and promote bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

This is Classic ASP right? Your code shows plus signs for string concatenation which is not Classic ASP.

How about:

```
If waabase <> "ALL" Then
    SQL_query = "SELECT * from Flytasks where waabase like '" & waabase & "'"
Else
    SQL_query = "SELECT * from Flytasks"
End If
```

And for a little bit of SQL injection protection you could change to:

```
SQL_query = "SELECT * from Flytasks where waabase like '" & Replace(waabase, "'", "''") & "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the query that produces the dropdown options, do something like this:

```
select  blabla
from    tbl
union all
select  'All'
```

(specify the 'All' as a literal since it doesn't exist on the table, use a union to connect it with the values that do exist)

Then in the query that uses the dropdown value selected, do something like this:

```
select  *
from    tbl
where   promptfield = promptvalue
union all
select  *
from    tbl
where   promptvalue = 'ALL'
```

Note that, when 'ALL' is selected in the dropdown, the first query in this union will basically return no results and the 2nd will run and produce all the results. When something other than all is selected, it will be used as criteria, the first query will produce its results, and the 2nd will just return nothing, essentially doing what you want.

Comment: I have just tried

SQL_query="SELECT * from Flytasks where waabase like '"+waabase+"' union all select * from Flytasks where waabase = 'ALL'"

but got 

[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too many fields defined.

Comment: How many columns are on the table? Might be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846776/union-all-query-too-many-fields-defined

Comment: before the union all there is 4 and just the one after, I can see from the link I need the same number each side, will read some more

Comment: They should be the same # of columns since you're selecting from the same table each time. By the way the promptvalue part of my sql above should be the name of the variable you've assigned to the prompt, and promptfield should be the name of the field on the table that is associated with your prompt/dropdown. I would write out actual code but I am only familiar with how to do this in php and mysql.

Comment: I have it ballanced, same both sides of union all but still the same error

Comment: What's the name of the variable you've given for the result of the dropdown?

Comment: waabase same as my example

Comment: Which is the same as the name of the field?

Comment: I ask because in the sql you said you tried I can't tell when you refer to "waabase" if it's the variable or the field. The first query should say that the field is like the dropdown. The second query should say that the dropdown (not the field) is equal to 'All'.

Comment: Sorry its both I have cut it right done to the following SQL_query="SELECT * from Flytasks where waabase  like '"+waabase+"' union all select * from Flytasks where waabase like 'ALL' Order by waabase ASC" and still get the same error.

Comment: The dropdown is named waabase and the database field is called waabase

Comment: You use "waabase" at both the top and the bottom (I don't know if that's the variable or the field, but whichever it is, it shouldn't be the same on both). In the top of the union it should be the field, in the bottom of the union it should be the variable.

Comment: I think I might be misunderstanding what your saying, in the database I have a column called waabase on the form I have a select named waabase and the variable on the page is waabase all the way though, I have done it this way for many sites which all work fine. Is this incorrect ? I find it easy to follow by doning this

Comment: It's fine but what I'm saying is in the sql you gave I'm pretty sure you're referring to waabase the field at both the top and the bottom layer. The bottom layer should instead refer to the variable.

Comment: Penny dropped :) its getting late, I have changed it to this SQL_query="SELECT * from Flytasks where waatasktype  like '"+waatasktype+"' UNION ALL SELECT * from Flytasks where '"+waatasktype+"' like 'ALL'" but error still the same