# How can I UNION ALL on all columns of a table in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, union, union-all

I have two select queries with the same number of columns (c.150) and I am trying to UNION ALL the two with:

```
SELECT * 
FROM query1

UNION ALL

SELECT * 
FROM query2
```

I am getting the error "Too many fields defined", but I understand that Access can process 255 fields? Given I don't want to have to write out every field name within each of my select queries, is there a practical way to achieve this union?

Comment: in theory the UNION ALL should not be the culprit here. Can you launch your 2 queries separately successfully ?

Comment: if you have more fields than Access can handle, you may need to split it into multiple UNION queries.

Comment: All parts of the UNION query counts: 2 * 150 = 300. See possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846776/union-all-query-too-many-fields-defined

Comment: SQL code smell: if you have 120+ columns each table then they are almost certainly not fully normalized a.k.a. you have design flaws.

Answer (score 1):

As Parfait mentions in his comment, this error is caused as Access is counting the column count of each of my tables towards the limit. 150 + 150 > 255 => Too many fields defined. See a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846776/union-all-query-too-many-fields-defined).

Provided you don't have too much data, an alternative is to write one into a table and append the other into the same table.